# Why is the start of the tag wiki information cut off for [language-comparison]?

Tags: bug, tags

Upon viewing the tags page, the front bit of the [language-comparison](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-comparison) tag description is cut off. (It's missing the 'Use this tag')

[image]

Why is it cut off? It shows fine on the page with the questions tagged with [language-comparison](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-comparison).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The system trims “Use this tag” off the front of all tag excerpts when displayed in limited space, expecting that many begin “Use this tag for questions about ...“ and the first words are redundant: the tag is “*for* questions about ...”.

There are very many tags you can see showing the same effect (a telltale sign is starting with a lower-case letter). “Use this tag on ...” doesn’t work out quite as well, leading to what you saw here.